# How to view search results from both Google and DuckDuckGo in one step?

Tags: google-search, duckduckgo

I am trying to use DuckDuckGo more and more in my daily work as a replacement for Google. Though, from time to time I find that Google returns more relevant results for my queries.

So, I would be happy to get results from DuckDuckGo, and if there are no relevant ones, I still want to find them via Google. I wonder if there some Chrome extension exists that, e.g. splits the screen vertically and shows both DuckDuckGo and Google results pages, using just a one-run query. 
Or some other ideas?

Now I have to search on DuckDuckGo first, then if nothing satisfactory found, I have to open Google and enter the query again.

How would you approach this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently found [an extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/duckduckgo-google-search/neocnbooikkdddiocamakaaeebkamlin) which makes the very thing I need. Seems like the guy heard the praise and created it as I couldn't find it before.

[image: Google search from DuckDuckGo]

Answer (score 0):

there's an even better [greasemonkey](http://www.greasespot.net/) script that adds a lot of searching options under duckduckgo's search bar, it's called [DuckDuckGo Extended](http://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/show/129505). you can customize it to include all sorts of websites and you can make use of the built-in DDG's !bangs. it looks like this:
[image: screenshot]